# Using JsonPath Step Functions variable inside an array using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-cdk, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to set up an EMR step from the CDK (typescript), using a variable from the state context object as a parameter, but I can't get it to work.

Here's what I tried:

```
const emrTask = new EmrAddStep(
  stack,
  name,
  {
    name: name,
    jar: jar,
    args: [
      '--arg_1',
      '$$.Execution.StartTime',
    ],
    clusterId: clusterId,
  }
);
```

During the state run `$$.Execution.StartTime` does not get replaced by the actual value.

I also tried this:

```
const emrTask = new EmrAddStep(
  stack,
  name,
  {
    name: name,
    jar: jar,
    args: [
      '--arg_1',
      JsonPath.stringAt('$$.Execution.StartTime')
    ],
    clusterId: clusterId,
  }
);
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot use JsonPath fields in an array, they must be used in objects
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`EvaluateExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-stepfunctions-tasks.EvaluateExpression.html) task to do that

```js
new tasks.EvaluateExpression(stack, name, {
  expression: `['--arg_1', $$.Execution.StartTime]`,
  resultPath: '$.emrArgs'
});
```

And then you can adapt your task creation like the following

```js
const emrTask = new EmrAddStep(
  stack,
  name,
  {
    name: name,
    jar: jar,
    args: sfn.JsonPath.listAt('$.emrArgs'),
    clusterId: clusterId,
  }
);
```

Could not find a way to do it in a single task though.